# ServiceStack Patch not deserializing json

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to add the ability to rename an entity and basically it works with Post but not with Patch as I would like. Here's what my request DTO looks like:

```
[Route("/UpdateArea/{AreaID}")]
public class UpdateArea : IReturn<Area>
{
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When using Post I get both the AreaID and Name present in the request DTO but when using Patch, I only get the AreaID (Name is null). Both request look the same in Fiddler except for the verb at the top that changes:

```
POST http://localhost:51690/api/UpdateArea/9 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:51690/Default.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:51690
Content-Length: 8
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=qg1xabozws2hdvpd5ynhcpiv; proxy=http://localhost:16918/proxy/0/

Name=aaa
```

That's with ServiceStack 4.0.9